# Modal dimmed and nothing clickable on it

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap Modal open when a button is clicked, it does open but the whole screen including the modal is dimmed and I can not click on any of the buttons on it. Any idea what I am doing wrong? I am using Bootstrap 4 beta 2

```html
    <html>
    <head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    
    <title>My site</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
     crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
    <script>
     $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#myInput').focus()
     })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <!-- Navigation -->
     <nav
      class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    
      <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
           <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
         </a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    
    
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
       aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
           aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">...</div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
           data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save
           changes</button>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    
    
    
     </nav>
    
    
    
     <!-- Footer -->
     <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
       <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; MySite
        2017</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    
    
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
      <script
       src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
      <script
       src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
    
    
    
      <!--modal-->
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal();
       });
      </script>
     </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your modal code outside of the nav tag as below. I'm honestly not 100% sure of the reason but I have had this issue before

**Don't** change any bootstrap css as it most likely will be problematic in the future. Just move the code a line down.

```html
    <html>
    <head th:fragment="head">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport"
     content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    <meta name="author" content="" />
    
    <title>My site</title>
    
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
     href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
     integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb"
     crossorigin="anonymous" />
    
    <script>
     $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#myInput').focus()
     })
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
     <!-- Navigation -->
     <nav
      class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
    
      <div class="container">
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
       <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse"
        data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal"
        data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
         <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
           <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
         </a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
         <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>

    
    
    
     </nav>
      
    
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
       aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
       <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
           aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">...</div>
         <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"
           data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save
           changes</button>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>      
    
    
     <!-- Footer -->
     <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
       <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; MySite
        2017</p>
      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    
    
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
      <script
       src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
      <script
       src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
       integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
       crossorigin="anonymous" async="async"></script>
    
    
    
      <!--modal-->
      <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal();
       });
      </script>
     </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: It worked, I'm surprised why it does not work when it's inside the <nav> tag

Comment: I believe it would be that the "fixed-top" class in your navbar overrides of the modal's z-index to 1030 when the black modal background has a z-index of 1040. So taking the code out of that nav tag lets bootstrap assign the needed z-index value of the modal-body to 1050 (above the backdrop)

Answer (score 0):

```
.modal-backdrop.show{
  z-index:1;
}
```

This will bring modal on the top.

```css
.modal-backdrop.show {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head th:fragment="head">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />

  <title>My site</title>

  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

  <script>
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
      $('#myInput').focus()
    })
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Navigation -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">

    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Home</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
       </button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Upload</button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
           <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
         </a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="5" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
           <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">...</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save
           changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </nav>



  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
      <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; MySite 2017
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>



    <!--modal-->
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myModal").modal();
      });
    </script>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```